# ASP.NET core remote debugging permission issue (vsdbg)

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug asp.net core application running in azure ubuntu vm via SSH and when I try to attach to the process I get this error message in Visual Studio 2017:

```
Failed to attach to process: The .NET Debugger (vsdbg) has insufficient privileges to debug this process. To debug this process, vsdbg must be running with root permissions.
```

I've given 'vsdbg' read & write permissions but still the error persists, how can I give this process root permissions, so that, I can debug the application.

Comment: There are several steps to set up root permissions (Pi example here https://www.hanselman.com/blog/RemoteDebuggingWithVSCodeOnWindowsToARaspberryPiUsingNETCoreOnARM.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I have just resolve the problem. 
In my case the problem was with user logged in. On Linux and on VS usernames must be the same. I was logged inside Linux as root and on VS as different username. After change Linux user the debugging process starter normally.

Comment: That's not a solution. Of course the usernames will be different.

Comment: That solved my problem. I had used "administrator@192.10.10.10" to connect to machine, while process which I wanted to debug was started using "root". Debugger could not attach until I have used "root@192.10.10.10" (so the same user name which started the process). You can check "User name" column on Available processes grid to check which user had started the process and it must be equal to the one you use in "Connection Target" field to connect.